# Debugging breeze js entity state

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal

So i keep getting 'ERROR: Cannot perform a 'setEntityState' on an entity that is in the process of being saved' in an application built using durandaljs, knockout and breeze. I am not really sure where to start debugging. It is a single page application and for some reason when changes are made the save is not triggered. But when I try to leave the page, the system identifies that there were changes and throws the error. I tried looking up this specific error on google and found nothing close to how to debug it. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can check what has been change while page is going to deactivate using drundaljs life cycle's method **canDeactivate**.

please specify your code for more help.